# ImageView can not display image using SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, simpleadapter

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] names = new String[]{"name1", "name2", "name3"};
    private String[] says = new String[]{"desc1", "desc2", "desc3"};
    private int[] imgIds = new int[]{R.mipmap.head_icon1, R.mipmap.head_icon2, R.mipmap.head_icon3};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Map<String, Object>> listitem = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            Map<String, Object> showitem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            showitem.put("touxiang", imgIds[i]);
            showitem.put("name", names[i]);
            showitem.put("says", says[i]);
            listitem.add(showitem);
        }

        //create one simpleAdapter
        SimpleAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listitem, R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"touxiang", "name", "says"}, new int[]{R.id.imgtou, R.id.name, R.id.says});
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_test);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgtou"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="#1D1D1C"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/says"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8px"
            android:textColor="#B4B4B9"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

but these images can be recognized by android studio.
[image]
[image]

anyone can help to find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You've used SimpleAdapter in your code.
But usage was wrong.
SimpleAdapter haven't image id as parameter.

Please look following URL.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter

```
public SimpleAdapter (Context context, 
            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, 
            int resource, 
            String[] from, 
            int[] to)
```

- **context(Context)**: The context where the View associated
  with this SimpleAdapter is running data  List: A List of Maps. Each
  entry in the List corresponds to one row in the list. The Maps
  contain the data for each row, and should include all the entries
  specified in "from"
- **resource(int)**: Resource identifier of a view
  layout that defines the views for this list item. The layout file
  should include at least those named views defined in "to"
- **from(String)**: A list of column names that will be added to the Map
  associated with each item.
- **to(int)**: The views that should display
  column in the "from" parameter. These should all be `TextViews`. The
  first N views in this list are given the values of the first N
  columns in the from parameter.

But you used image ids array to "to" fields.

```
//create one simpleAdapter
SimpleAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
   getApplicationContext(),
   listitem,
   R.layout.list_item,
   new String[]{"touxiang", "name", "says"},
   new int[]{R.id.imgtou, R.id.name, R.id.says} //You used wrong values. This should be textview ids.
);
```

So you cannot use SimpleAdapter with your purpose.

You should customize Adapter class to your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
getApplicationContext(), 
listitem, 
R.layout.list_item,
new String[]{"touxiang", "name", "says"}, 
new int[]{R.mipmap.head_icon1, R.mipmap.head_icon2, R.mipmap.head_icon3}
);
```

Or you can use Picasso Library for setting and Loading Images.